# How to override the og:url meta tag with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs and working on a site that uses [react-document-meta](https://github.com/kodyl/react-document-meta) to generate meta data. I would like to override the og:url tag and was wondering if there is a way to do this. Being new to ReactJs, I couldn't figure out a way looking at the library. I appreciate any help.

Thanks,
-DJ

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [docs](https://github.com/kodyl/react-document-meta#usage) and [source code](https://github.com/kodyl/react-document-meta/blob/c5021178597049b187e761dd66835055deb26567/lib/index.js#L69)

```
const meta = {
  title: 'Some Meta Title',
  description: 'I am a description, and I can create multiple tags',
  canonical: 'http://example.com/path/to/page',  // this will be doubled as og:url
  meta: {
    charset: 'utf-8',
    name: {
      keywords: 'react,meta,document,html,tags'
    },
    property : {
      'og:url' : 'http://example.com/overriden_url' // but here you can override the autogenerated og:url
    }
  }
};
```

Keep in mind it only makes sense when rendering on the server-side, as setting `meta` properties on the client-side (in the browser) has no effect on what the Facebook parser sees when scrapping the page.